# How do you generate random semi-unitary matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, statistics, numerical-methods

I know that we can sample from the Haar distribution to generation random orthogonal matrices, but I don't know how to generate random semi-unitary matrices. All attempts to find information about this have pointed me to the Python code related to orthogonal group or unitary group sampling, neither of which I think is directly helpful.

I've seen some answers that suggest that you can just generate a $m \times n$ matrix and do the QR-decomp and take the $Q$ matrix as a semi-orthogonal solution, but some Python testing revealed that these matrices weren't actually semi-orthogonal. Also this method just doesn't really make sense, because when we generalize QR decomp to allow rectangular matrices, $Q$ becomes a $m \times m$ unitary matrix which is also not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't *proved* that this gives a nice measure, it seems doing something like sampling $\mathbf{U}_1$ from $U(n)$ and sampling $\mathbf{U}_2$ from $U(m)$ and then calculating:

$$
\mathbf{U}_1 \textbf{diag}_{n,m}(1,1,1...) \mathbf{U}_2
$$

should work. (Where $\textbf{diag}_{n,m}(d_1, d_2, ..)$ gives an $n\times m$ diagonal matrix with diagonal entries given by the $d_i$.)

Comment: I think you can actually drop one of those unitaries -- whichever acts on the smaller space.